# Get Code Isin from Bloomberg with Excel formula

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the all Code Isin that compose a ticker using the Excel formula ? I can't find the formula on Internet.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: If the ticker refers to an instrument that has an ISIN code, then =BDP(ticker,”ID_ISIN”) will return that code.

Comment: ws.Range("A2").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=BDP(""" & ws.Cells(1, 3).Value & ", ""ID_ISIN"")"
        BloombergUI.RefreshAllStaticData

Comment: @DS_London Do you know please, how to get all the Code Isin (for example 500 for SP 500) ? Do I need to use the function For/Next ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In response to the follow-up, the best way to get the members of an index from Bloomberg is to use BQL (Bloomberg Query Language). There is a 'BQL Builder' option in the Bloomberg toolbar, or use the Function Builder (the sytnax is slightly different).

For the OP's question, enter this formula in a cell:

`=BQL("members('SPX INDEX')","ID_ISIN")`

It will expand, and show all the members of the S&P and their ISINs.

Comment: Hello @DS_London, Is it possible to get also the NAME of ID_ISIN like =BQL("members('SPX INDEX')","ID_ISIN", "NAME") ? Thank you !

Comment: @Marie =BQL("members('SPX INDEX')","ID_ISIN,NAME")

Comment: There is some option, please, in this formula to freez the values ? I want to hide the formula. Thank you for your help !